# concat with space while update sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where I am storing col values

```
sno  col1   col2 
1    col2       concat(col1,' ',col2)
```

If I insert value as `concat(col1,col2)` then its working fine but if I insert `concat(col1,' ',col2)` its giving me an error

How can I store `CONCAT(col1, ' ', col2)` as a string literal in `Col1`?.

```
UPDATE MAPPING SET col1 = 'CONCAT(col1,' ',col2)'
```

Comment: You need to show your complete query statement.

Comment: SQL Server also has `+` for concatenation. Try `col1 + ' ' + col2` .

Comment: BTW, don't store those concatenated values in the table. You'd end up with inconsistent data. Either create a _view_, or add a _computed column_.

Comment: UPDATE MAPPING SET col1  = 'CONCAT(col1,' ',col2)'  ;     I am maintaining col names in MAPPING table  , and I want to set the col1 value as shown above

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @jarlh : I have to store them in a table because later i have to fetch them using dynamic query

Comment: A view or a computed column wouldn't stop that!

Comment: Remove the quotes surrounding `'CONCAT(col1,' ',col2)'` - it's not a string, it outputs a string.

Comment: @PeterSmith Incorrect syntax near ',col2)'.

Comment: @Diado : can't remove the quotes because the value would be col1 col2,  I need value to be concat(col1,' ',col2)  .so that i can fetch it from another table using dynamic query

Comment: Wait. you want the value of the column to be the string literal `CONCAT(col1,' ',col2)`, not the output of the `CONCAT` function? Are you then using that to build dynamic SQL? *(be aware there's a chance that'll be open to SQL injection)*. If so, double the quotes in the middle - `UPDATE MAPPING SET col1 = 'CONCAT(col1,'' '',col2)';`

Comment: This definitely sounds like a injection nightmare. You should really not be storing expression that need to be evaluated at run time in your table(s).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the quotes as

```
UPDATE MAPPING 
SET col1 = CONCAT(col1, ' ',col2)
--WHERE <Type your conditions here if needed>
```

Which is the same as

```
UPDATE MAPPING 
SET col1 = col1 + ' ' + Col2
--WHERE <Type your conditions here if needed>
```

If you really want to store this as a string then

```
UPDATE MAPPING 
SET col1 = 'CONCAT(col1, '' '',col2)'
--WHERE <Type your conditions here if needed>
```

Comment: can' remove the quotes , in my case i need CONCAT(col1, ' ',col2) as value not col1 col2

Comment: @sheetalverma See the last query in my answer.

Comment: @Sami, if the OP had made _any_ of the edits that rendered this question readable, I might vote to reopen, mostly so you could get your answer accepted. That's not the case, and from the OP's profile, it seems they don't accept answers anyway, so I'm giving you a +1 and moving on.

Answer (score 1):

SO you need one more set of quotes:

```
UPDATE MAPPING SET col1 = 'CONCAT(col1,'' '',col2)'
```